# How to solve this recurrence relation - $T(n) = (2^n)T(n/2) + n^n$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

I have got this recurrence relation: $T(n) = (2^n)T(n/2) + (n^n)$

This cannot be solved using Master's Theorem (for $T(n) = aT(n/b) + O(n^k)$) because $a$ is not constant but depends on $n$.

Below is my approach to this problem (trying using Recurrence Relation):

$T(n) = 2^nT(n/2) + n^n \\ \\
= 2^n[2^{n/2}T(n/2^2) + (n/2)^{n/2}] + n^n \\ \\
= 2^{n(1+1/2)}T(n/2^2) + (2n)^{n/2} + n^n \\ \\
= 2^{n(1+1/2+1/2^2)}T(n/2^3) + 2^nn^{n/4} + (2n)^{n/2} + n^n$

As shown in the last line, I cannot find any closed mathematical form for the terms after `T(n/8)`.

Assume: `T(1) = c`

Comment: Why did you tag this as algorithms? Is this from the analysis of some known algorithm?

Comment: @mvw no, this is not from any known algorithm. I got this relation from a book in examples which cannot be solved using Master's theorem.

Comment: The recurrence relation involves $n/2$, so it seems valid only for even $n$. If you have only $T(1)=c$, you can only determine $T$ for powers of $2$. I'd write it $T(2^n)=2^{2^n}T(2^{n-1})+(2^n)^{2^n}$

Comment: @ajotatxe apart from the recurrence relation, no other constraint was mentioned in the book. I made up the base case myself.

Comment: $$\frac{T(2^k)}{4^{2^k}}=\frac{T(2^{k-1})}{4^{2^{k-1}}}+\frac{(2^k)^{2^k}}{4^{2k}}\implies T(2^k)=4^{2^k}\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{(2^i)^{2^i}}{4^{2^i}}+4^{2^k}\frac{T(1)}4\implies\ldots$$

Comment: @Did Is there an easy way to get either a closed form or tight asymptotics after that? Given the sum, I expect something doubly exponential in $k$, but is there a simpl-ish method to pinpoint the constant in the exponent?

Comment: $$\lim\frac{T(2^k)}{(2^k)^{2^k}}=1$$

Comment: @Did Oh. Thank you. I didn't expect that, but in hindsight it makes sense (the terms of the sum grow so quickly, only the last one matters).

Comment: @ClementC. Exactly.